# Cron Job Executing Twice on Tomcat 8

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, configuration, cron, tomcat8

I have the following piece of code :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?")
public void sendScheduleSms() {...}
```

It is a spring-boot project. When I run this as the spring-boot application it works fine and Job is executed only once. But when I create a war file and deploy it on Tomcat, same job executed twice. Can anyone tell how I can avoid that? I have seen a couple of solutions but they are of spring MVC where they have web.xml file. one thing I am sure of is that beans are getting initiated twice.

I have used following annotations: Its an existing project I am just doing bug fixing.

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.wallet")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
```

They are used in the main class.
**p.s. When I sun application normally Job runs only once. But when I modify server.xml in the conf folder to point my application at the root if run the Job twice.**

Comment: Why did you deploy it on Tomcat? Spring Boot has embedded Tomcat once you add the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web` and the scheduled tasks work fine for me.

Comment: As I said, it is an existing Project and it has some JSPs as well. Therefore I need to deploy it on tomcat.